# android service not working when app enters background in titanium

Tags: android, service, titanium-mobile

Hi I try to develop a simple Android service application using Titanium by following their tutorial. It works well when the application is in foreground, but when I press back button it kills the app and my service is not running.
Below is the code I used and the log I got when the app enters background. Please let me know where I am going wrong. (I am using Titanium SDK 2.0.1.GA2 and Android SDK 2.2 with Android Runtime v8/Rhino].

My app.js file:

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.createServiceIntent( { url: 'logservice.js' } );
// Service should run its code every 10 seconds.
intent.putExtra('interval', 10000);
 // A message that the service should 'echo'
intent.putExtra('message_to_echo', 'Titanium rocks!');

var service = Titanium.Android.createService(intent);
service.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
Titanium.API.info('Service code resumes, iteration ' + e.iteration);
});
service.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
Titanium.API.info('Service code pauses, iteration ' + e.iteration);
/* if (e.iteration === 3) {
    Titanium.API.info('Service code has run 3 times, will now stop it.');
    service.stop();
} */
});
service.start();
```

And my logservice.js file is:

```
var service = Titanium.Android.currentService;
var intent = service.intent;
var message = intent.getStringExtra("message_to_echo");
Titanium.API.info("Hello World!  I am a Service.  I have this to say: " + message);
```

I included that service tag in tiapp.xml

And this is the log I am getting when I press back button:

```
W/KeyCharacterMap(  322): No keyboard for id 0
W/KeyCharacterMap(  322): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
E/TiBaseActivity(  322): (main) [62040,92891] Layout cleanup.
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9526 objects / 480272 bytes in 115ms
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 12770 objects / 693152 bytes in 80ms
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8846 objects / 508872 bytes in 77ms
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8976 objects / 512112 bytes in 78ms
D/EventEmitter(  322): callHandler function not available for resume
W/TiAnalyticsSvc(  322): (Thread-15) [29966,122857] Analytics Service Started
I/TiAnalyticsSvc(  322): (Thread-15) [69,122926] Sending 1 analytics events.
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7386 objects / 436936 bytes in 87ms
D/NativeCrypto(  322): Freeing OpenSSL session
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1581 objects / 89648 bytes in 71ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  322): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.588MB for 87396-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 12 objects / 712 bytes in 76ms
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 956 objects / 49400 bytes in 88ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  322): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.624MB for 87396-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 75ms
W/TiAnalyticsSvc(  322): (Thread-15) [3772,126698] Stopping Analytics Service
D/SntpClient(   60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not     supported by protocol
```